# Store and Restore previous userinput texfield

Tags: java, user-input, textfield

I have two Textfields that can be input by user and will be used for calculation later (Number only), lets say InputX and InputY. And two radio button, Rad1 and Rad2.

When user Choose Rad1, **Both TextFiled are Input-able** by User and Stored to memory/variable when user input in it. But when user choose Rad2, **only InputX is available** and InputY is *InputY.setText("InputX only")*. If User choose the Rad1 back, i want to **restore the value** that user input to the **InputY previously**, not showing "**InputX Only**".

So, My Question is: How to **get the previous value from userinput** when user choose the Rad1 back, since ***its has been overridden*** by Rad2 InputY.setText("InputX Only") ?

Please create a full code example with all possible/alternative code, i'm new in java.

Note: Im using Netbeans v8.0.2 and create form using built in form builder/designer

Comment: Since you're already using variables to store the values of the fields, just use a third variable for the constant used in InputY and don't alter the user entered value in your y-variable. You can just restore that variable to the field when the user selects Rad1.

Comment: But once you setText to one of those inputs, the text is gone. He needs to store the user input somewhere.

Comment: _Please create a full code example with all possible/alternative code_ is not the best way to end a question.

Comment: @Andrei indeed, that why i ask this question, i lost last user input in InputY because overridden by my code when user select Rad2 and the InputY set to setText("InputX Only")

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InputValidator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static final String INPUT_X_ONLY = "InputX Only";
private String temp = "";

public InputValidator() {
    initComponents();
    jRadioButton1.setSelected(true);
    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);

    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            jTextField2.setEditable(true);
            jTextField2.setText(temp);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            jTextField2.setEditable(false);
            temp = jTextField2.getText();
            jTextField2.setText(INPUT_X_ONLY);
        }
    });
}
```